# Sort an array based on another array's values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with values as follows:-

```
$Array1 = array("myfirst_value", "mysecond_value", "mythird_value"}
```

Now for my another array, the listing comes in randomly as follows:-

```
$Array2 = array
(
    [4] => myfirst_value
    [8] => myforth_value
    [21] => mysecond_value
    [7] => myfifth_value
    [17] => mysixth_value
    [20] => mythird_value
    [16] => myseventh_value
)
```

What I am hoping to achieve is that the $Array2 gets sorted based on the order of values in $Array1.

So, I am hoping that $Array2 gets sorted and becomes:-

```
$Array2 = array
(
        [4] => myfirst_value
        [21] => mysecond_value
        [20] => mythird_value


        [7] => myfifth_value
        [8] => myforth_value
        [16] => myseventh_value
        [17] => mysixth_value

)
```

Notice, the values of Array1 are sorted first and rest are just outputted without any order.

Thanks

Comment: Sort by http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly

```
$Array1 = array("myfirst_value", "mysecond_value", "mythird_value");

$Array2 = array
(
    4 => myfirst_value,
    8 => myforth_value,
    21 => mysecond_value,
    7 => myfifth_value,
    17 => mysixth_value,
    20 => mythird_value,
    16 => myseventh_value
);

// Remove elements of the 1st array from the 2nd
function f ($v) { global $Array1;  return in_array($v, $Array1);}
$a1 = array_filter($Array2, 'f');    
// Take the rest elements
$a2 = array_diff_key($Array2, $a1);
// Combine back 
print_r($a1+$a2);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [4] => myfirst_value
    [21] => mysecond_value
    [20] => mythird_value
    [8] => myforth_value
    [7] => myfifth_value
    [17] => mysixth_value
    [16] => myseventh_value
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for taking out time to do this. Unfortunately, this is giving me white screen. I guess it's not supported in my php version.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: @Steve Try now - i remove the anonymous function

Comment: Thanks a lot splash. Unfortunately, it's not doing anything now. $a1 is basically coming out empty

Comment: https://eval.in/380070 there it works. I look later, what else may does not work in your version

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `uasort()` function as

```
uasort($Array2, function($a,$b) use (&$Array1){
    foreach($Array1 as $key => $value){
        if($a == $value){
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if($b == $value){
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($a == $b){ return 0;}  return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/380288)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from splash's perfect answer, this also works:-

```
 $Sorted_Array = array_merge(
        array_intersect($Array1, $Array2), 
        array_diff($Array2, $Array1)
 );
```

Comment: array_intersect($Array1, $Array2) -  looses the keys. It is wrong answer :)

Comment: :-D ... now ofcourse I can't even compare to your answer :)

Comment: I'm serious - result of function will have keys 0,1,2... But You want to save them from source array